# Knockout custom binding handler for Polymer core-selector - setting 'selected' attribute is not updating the element

Tags: knockout.js, polymer, bindinghandlers

The binding handler and the HMTL.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.radioGroupChanged = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var newValueAccessor = function () {
            return {
                change: function () {
                    var selectedValue = $(element).attr('selected');
                    value(selectedValue);
                }
            }
        };

        ko.bindingHandlers.event.init(element, newValueAccessor, allBindingAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).attr('selected', valueAccessor()());
    }
}
```

```html
<paper-radio-group style="position:absolute; left:160px; top:0px;" data-bind="radioGroupChanged: MessagePriority" }">
    <paper-radio-button label="High">
    </paper-radio-button>
    <paper-radio-button label="Medium">
    </paper-radio-button>
    <paper-radio-button label="Low">
    </paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>
```

When it hits the update function, if I manually update the selected attribute of the radio group element it changes to "select" straight away.

$(element).attr('selected', '0');

then $(element).attr('selected')  is always 'selected'.

I have no idea why it's not retaining the value.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Polymer has its own data binding mechanism, what do you need knockout for?`

Answer (score 0):

The `selected` **attribute** is not meant to be a indicator which element is selected and only describes the initial state. The actual `selected` **property** on the DOM element is holding this information. So in your case you would do the following:

```
element.selected = valueAccessor();
```

or to read:

```
if(element.selected == 1) alert("Yeah Medium was selected");
```

Hope that helps.